# Preload a cdn cached files

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cdn, preload

I have a files that is cached in some cdn.

in my local environment you can read the markup in browser as

```
<script src="/js/cool.js"></script>
```

but once it in production it goes like:

```
<script src="/js/cool.js.pagespeed.ce.l2D9mD1nmX.js"></script>
```

`.pagespeed.ce.l2D9mD1nmX.js` means it was being cached

now i was wondering if its advisable or a practice to preload a file that is already being cached in cdn?

because i am doing

```
<link rel="preload" type="application/javascript" href="/js/cool.js" as="script">
```

in my `<head>` and this will give me warning of :

*The resource (the preload file) was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.*

because technically `/js/cool.js` is no longer existing in the dom

Answer (score 0):

> Use a preload plugin in your module bundler.

**Q. Is it advisable or a practice to preload a file that is already being cached in cdn?**

A. Yes, it is, assuming your *cool.js* actually needs to be preloaded.

---

Now, the warning is actually expected. See, `cool.js.pagespeed.ce.l2D9mD1nmX.js` and `cool.js` are two different files on the server. Your file `cool.js.pagespeed.ce.l2D9mD1nmX.js` is actually a clone of `code.js` produced by your [module-bundler](https://www.slant.co/topics/3900/~best-frontend-javascript-module-bundlers) for certain [reasons](https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/adding-hashes-to-filenames/). What you are doing is preloading `cool.js`, the code of which never gets executed in production and thus the warning - *...preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event*. But, what you actually need to do is preload `cool.js.pagespeed.ce.l2D9mD1nmX.js`. Assuming you are using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as your module-bundler, you need a plugin called [preload-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin) to achieve the same.

Comment: The l2D9mD1nmX in cool.js.pagespeed.ce.l2D9mD1nmX.js is a random id that i believe change overtime. In that case having it declare in preload will possibly become different once this change. Is there a way to declare it dynamically?  so it will always matched the id that cdn provide. Uhm this is a conventional set up and we don't use webpack.